# How to solve error protocol recording video in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying record video with AVFoundation. In objective c I had a protocol definition to delegate in .h:

```
 @protocol AVCaptureManagerDelegate <NSObject>
 - (void)didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
                                  error:(NSError *)error;
 @end


 @interface AVCaptureManager : NSObject

 @property (nonatomic, assign) id<AVCaptureManagerDelegate> delegate;
```

And in swift need this code to save in out url with recordingDelegate, but need delegate:

```
self.movieFileOut.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(filePath, recordingDelegate)
```

I'm confused..
Thanks!!

Comment: trust me, we are also confused by your post.

Comment: for save my video, I need use this method:    self.fileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(filePath, delegate) and delegate in objective c was defined with a protocol in my .h class but now, I don't know if I'm using this bad or not is how i'm trying. protocol proto{
    var dele : AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {get set}
}

Comment: more easy, how can convert this to swift?: NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"file://" stringByAppendingString:filePath]];
    [self.fileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:fileURL recordingDelegate:self];

Comment: if I write a protocol for delegate :      protocol proto{
    var dele : AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {get set}   
}     I can't call this with startRecordingToOutputFileURL

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code in swift fore recording a video. The first thing is to define a delegate :

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class VideoDelegate : NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate
{

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
    println("capture output : finish recording to \(outputFileURL)")
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("capture output: started recording to \(fileURL)")
    }

}
```

After that , calling the startRecordingToOutputFileURL (Assuming session is a AVCaptureSession):

```
let videoDelegate = VideoDelegate()
let fileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
session.addOutput(fileOutput)
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString
let outputPath = "\(documentsPath)/output.mov"
let outputFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
fileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(outputFileUrl, recordingDelegate: videoDelegate)
```